# EF7 not saving object graph

Tags: entity-framework-core

I expect I'll feel like an idiot when I figure out the answer to this, but I just cannot figure out why EF7 isn't saving the object graph the same way I'm used to it working in EF6.

My context is:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext, IBloggingContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Make Blog.Url required
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .Required();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .Reference(p => p.Blog)
            .InverseCollection(b => b.Posts)
            .ForeignKey(p => p.BlogId);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    private ICollection<Post> _posts;

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get
        {
            if (_posts == null)
            { _posts = new Collection<Post>(); }
            return _posts;
        }
        protected set
        { _posts = value; }

    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I then write the following code:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = new Blog() { Url = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
    blog.Posts.Add(new Post() { Title = "Foo", Content = "Foo" });
    blog.Posts.Add(new Post() { Title = "Bar", Content = "Bar" });

    db.Blogs.Add(blog);
    var count = db.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} records saved to database", count);

    return blog.BlogId;
}
```

After `SaveChanges` is called the `blog` object has a `BlogId` but the `BlogId` in the two `Post` objects is still -1 and nothing gets added to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of EF 7 beta 6, calling `DbSet<T>.Add(obj)` only adds `obj`, not all of the entities associated with `obj`.

In your case, you also need to call `db.Posts.Add(post)` for each new post.

This behavior will likely change before EF 7 RTM's. You can follow changes to this API by watching this issue on GitHub: [Decide on Add() behavior with graphs #2726](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2726)